# Adding a new volume to a pseudo-distributed Hadoop node failing silently

Tags: amazon-ec2, hadoop, hive

Im attempting to add a new volume to a Hadoop pseudo-distributed node, by adding the location of the volume in `dfs.name.dir` in `hdfs-site.xml`, and i can see the lock file in this location - but try as i might, it seems that when i load files (using hive) these locations are hardly used (even though the lock files, and some sub-folders appears.. so Hadoop clearly had access to them). When the main volume comes close to running out of space, i get the following exception:

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hive-ubuntu/hive_2011-02-24_15-39-15_997_1889807000233475717/-ext-10000/test.csv could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1417)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:643)
```

Any pointers on how to add new volumes to Hadoop ? FWIW im using EC2.

Answer (score 1):

When adding new disks / capacity to a data node Hadoop does not guarantee that the disks will be load balanced fairly (Ex: It will not put more blocks on drives with more free space). The best way I have solved this is to increase the replication factor (Ex: From 2 to 3).

```
hadoop fs -setrep 3 -R /<path>
```

Watch the 'under replicated blocks' report on the name node. As soon as this reaches 0, decrease the replication factor (Ex: From 3 to 2). This will randomly delete replicas from the system which should balance out the local node.

```
hadoop fs -setrep 2 -R /<path>
```

It's not going to be 100% balanced, but it should be in a lot better shape then it was before. This is covered in the Hadoop wiki to some extent. If you are running pseudo-distributed, and have no other data nodes then the balancer script will not help you.

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#If_I_add_new_DataNodes_to_the_cluster_will_HDFS_move_the_blocks_to_the_newly_added_nodes_in_order_to_balance_disk_space_utilization_between_the_nodes.3F

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do, according to the [FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#If_I_add_new_DataNodes_to_the_cluster_will_HDFS_move_the_blocks_to_the_newly_added_nodes_in_order_to_balance_disk_space_utilization_between_the_nodes.3F):

1. Manually copy files in HDFS to a new name, delete the old files, then rename the new files to be what they were originally.
2. Increase the replication factor temporarily, setting it back once blocks have balanced out between nodes.
3. Remove the full node, wait for its blocks to replicate to the other nodes, then bring it back up. This doesn't really help because your full node is still full when you bring it back online.
4. Run the rebalancer script on the head node.

I'd try running #4 first, then #2.